# memory access error on official example spacy code for entity linking

Tags: nlp, spacy

Ive tried to follow the instructions on the official documentation at:
https://spacy.io/usage/training#entity-linker

Basicially I use these commands:

```
python create_kb.py -o kb en_core_web_lg
python train_entitiy_linker.py kb kb/vocab/
```

Of course I didnt change the example code.

As a result I get following output

```
Created blank 'en' model with vocab from 'kb/vocab'
Memory access error (memory dumped)
```

Ive tested on Fedora 22, python 3.7, spacy 2.2 and 2.3
Do you have any clue? Or is it a bug

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use

```
python train_entitiy_linker.py kb/kb kb/vocab/
```

instead.